# Java - Should an iterator for a doubly linked list with sentinels look like this?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, iterator

I'm writing my own implementation of a doubly linked list as an exercise, but I don't think I fully understand how to utilize the sentinel nodes at the start and end of the list. I would like to ask about using sentinels in the iterator in particular. Here's my iterator (not finished):

```
private class MyIterator implements Iterator<T> {
    private Node current = first;

    public boolean hasNext() {
        if(current.next.next == null) return false;
        else return true;
    }

    public T next() {
        current = current.next;
        if(current.next == null) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return current.data;
    }
}
```

What I want to know is if there's any way I can utilize the tail sentinel in the next() and hasNext() methods to avoid null checks. Or is this fine as it is?

Comment: No this code will fail: if `current.next` is `null` you'll get NPE.

Comment: Isn't `hasNext()` supposed to tell you if the current object has a next item? Not if the current items next item has a next item. That would be `nextHasNext()` or something

Comment: In `hasNext()` it should be `return current.next != null;`.

Comment: It's like that because of the sentinel node. It's set to return false if the next node is the sentinel node. It works fine.

Comment: The whole point of the sentinel is that you won't have null checks. You check whether you have reached the sentinel.

Comment: In your code, I don't think next() ever returns the first element.

Comment: The first element is a sentinel node so that would be why it never returns it.